# Change class depending on selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Full Joomla Code for Selectbox 1

```
<div class="controls">
 <select id="jform_params_wrapper_threed_typeofcontent1" name="jform[params][wrapper][threed_typeofcontent1]" class="chzn-done" style="display: none;">
    <option value="video" selected="selected">Video</option>
    <option value="image">Image</option>
    <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
 </select>
 <div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-with-drop chzn-container-active" style="width: 220px;" title="" id="jform_params_wrapper_threed_typeofcontent1_chzn">
  <a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
   <span>Video</span>
   <div><b></b></div>
  </a>
  <div class="chzn-drop">
   <div class="chzn-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
   <ul class="chzn-results">
    <li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Video</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Image</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Disabled</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

By using this code I change the value's from the selectboxes but these are not yet shown at the Joomla Backend because of the `.chzn-results .result-selected.highlighted`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jform_params_wrapper_threed_typeofcontent1').bind('change', function (e) {
    $('#jform_params_wrapper_threed_contentlink1type').val('default');
    $('#jform_params_wrapper_threed_contentmodal1type').val('select');
  }).trigger('change');

  $('#jform_params_wrapper_threed_contentlink1type').bind('change', function (e) {
    $('#jform_params_wrapper_threed_contentmodal1type').val('select');
  }).trigger('change');
 });
```

I am at a loss here what should I do to change those classes to the other li elements depending on the set value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to trigger .change();
so change `.trigger('change')` to `.change()`.

That should do the trick.

Comment: That is not going to make `result-selected highlighted` these come at another <li>

Comment: you should add `.change()` to the select box that should change. Workflow: select the value in select box and trigegr .change for that selectbox (#jform_params_wrapper_threed_typeofcontent1).